# Gruntfile.js tasks... ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

Trying to get Grunt to concat my CSS files into one called production.css

Here is the output from the command prompt

```
C:\Users\josha\Desktop\Repos\AJAX Project - Grunt Test>grunt

C:\Users\josha\Desktop\Repos\AJAX Project - Grunt Test\Gruntfile.js:2
  "name": "AjaxPmodule.exports = function(grunt) {
        ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

C:\Users\josha\Desktop\Repos\AJAX Project - Grunt Test>grunt

C:\Users\josha\Desktop\Repos\AJAX Project - Grunt Test\Gruntfile.js:2
  "name": "AjaxPmodule.exports = function(grunt) {
        ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

C:\Users\josha\Desktop\Repos\AJAX Project - Grunt Test>
```

Here is my Gruntfile

```
{
  "name": "AjaxPmodule.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

concat: {   
    dist: {
        src: [
            'css/*.css', // All JS in the libs folder
        ],
        dest: 'css/production.css',
    }
}

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};roject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

I'm using the grunt-contrib-concat to concat my files. The version is "^0.5.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have for some reason gotten some extra text into your file. It should start with `module.exports` and you also have something extra in the end.

I think what you did was basically to paste your grunt code into a code snippet that looks like package.json:

```
{
   "name": "ajaxProject",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "~0.4.1",
      "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0"
   }
}
```

Try this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {   
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'css/*.css', // All JS in the libs folder
                ],
                dest: 'css/production.css',
            }
        }

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

}
```

Comment: Great, update the reason. As said, looks like you have pasted your gruntcode into something that looks like package.json snippet.